# Social network plugin + Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, social-networking

I spent the morning looking for a good social network plugin that could help me in the developing on my Web Application using Rails 3.
The problem is that all that I found :

insoshi
Commuinty engine
Tog
Lovd by less

Are projected for previous version of RoR.
Do you know if there is any such plugin that is 100 % compatible or/and designed for Rails 3 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/ging/social_stream

Very opinionated and a generator (as opposed to plugin), but might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/salkar/inkwell

Inkwell provides simple way to add social networking features like comments, reblogs, favorites, following/followers, communities and timelines to your Ruby on Rails application.